# Solution with 2 project does not compile

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got solution with 2 projects.
In first project I've got Frame and some controls, in second - CForcesEditorDialog:CDialog.
Ofcouse I whant to compare them.
But this error don't give me compile project:

> MainFrame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   __thiscall CForcesEditorDialog::CForcesEditorDialog(class CWnd *,class MainFrame *)" (??0CForcesEditorDialog@@QAE@PAVCWnd@@PAVMainFrame@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "protected: int __thiscall
>   MainFrame::OnCreate(struct tagCREATESTRUCTA *)"
>   (?OnCreate@MainFrame@@IAEHPAUtagCREATESTRUCTA@@@Z)

```
class CForcesEditorDialog;

class MainFrame : public CFrameWnd
{
    CForcesEditorDialog* forcesEditorDialog;    

public:
    MainFrame();    
    ~MainFrame();   
    //virtual void CreateChildControls( void );
    //afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT, CPoint);

protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

int MainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    forcesEditorDialog = new CForcesEditorDialog(this,this);//CForcesEditorDialog(this,this);   
}




class CForcesEditorDialog : public CDialog
{
    //For including ForcesBar
    ForcesBar* m_forcesBar;
    MainFrame* pMainFrame;
public:
    CForcesEditorDialog(CWnd* _pParentWnd = NULL, MainFrame* _pMainFrame = NULL);   // standard constructor
}

CForcesEditorDialog::CForcesEditorDialog(CWnd* _pParentWnd, MainFrame* _pMainFrame)
: CDialog(IDD_CUR_DIALOG, _pParentWnd),
      p_expander    (0),
      p_selectedItem(0),
      m_enabled     (false)
{
    m_forcesBar = new ForcesBar();
    pMainFrame = _pMainFrame;
}
```

May be I've got a problem with including this projects. I had never wite solution with 2 projects. Have you got any ideas about it ?

Comment: Did you add the necessary project references so that the projects can see the things they depend on?  (Do both projects depend on eachother?  If so, you might have a circular reference problem.)

Comment: I have no circular redefinition. In *.h files I use only pointers and not include classes of these pointers in such files. While in *.cpp files I have all necessary includes.

Comment: When project A depends on project B, the linker won't know to add both projects to the final build product (and will fail) unless you add a reference from project A to project B.  (Right-click on project A > References > Add).  Another method is to manually add the .lib output file from project B to project A, as @Javier suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a linkage error. Visual Studio finds CForcesEditorDialog at compile time but it didn't at link time. You have to add the .lib file of the second project in the project settings of the first one ([Property Pages -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba1z7822.aspx)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another way to possibly achieve this is to add a project reference to the second project to the first project, although circular project references might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Is CForcesEditorDialog part of the project you compile? In other words is implementation file (cpp) for CForcesEditorDialog included in a project giving you this error message?
Is it a part of another project or DLL?

Comment: I nave error message at line  forcesEditorDialog = new CForcesEditorDialog(this,this). CForcesEditorDialog is a part of second project which I want to use in this one. CForcesEditorDialog have complicated relations with other classes from second project. So, in first project in header files I use line <class CForcesEditorDialog> while in .cpp files I write all include <#include CForcesEditorDialog>.

Answer (score 0):

try cut -pasting  class CForcesEditorDialog before class MainFrame

should do the trick

Comment: You mean to put this classes in one file?

Comment: i thought you have them in 1 file. try in one file, or when linking CForcesEditorDialog needs to be before MainFrame ( i assume you also include headers, because i don't see it here)

Answer (score 0):

What type of project is  CForcesEditorDialog in? Is it a static lib or a dynamic dll?

If it's dynamic, you will need to export the functions and classes from the dll that you want to use in your exe. This tutorial mentions exporting: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c4017/MFC-DLL-TUTORIAL-PART-1.htm

With AFX_EXT_CLASS. You would use it in your class declaration to export it from your dll, e.g.:

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CForcesEditorDialog : public CDialog
{
```

Comment: The type of first and second projects is Static Library (.lib).

Comment: In that case Javier De Pedro's answer might be the solution you need.